# What the reason of error "ORA-03135: Connection lost contact" when migration Microsoft OracleClient to ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, migration, odp.net, oracleclient

Recently decided to make the migration. And on some database servers all works fine, but on the other for some unknown reason errors occur.
I'm use the following code:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection _conn = 
                new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection("Data Source=[TNS_NAME];User Id=[USER_ID];Password=[PASS];");
            _conn.Open();
            Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection _conn1 =
                new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("Data Source=[HOST/TNS_NAME];User Id=[USER_ID];Password=[PASS];Validate Connection = true");
            _conn1.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

on the line `_conn1.Open()` i get an error "ORA-03135: Connection lost contact"
Why this phenomenon can occur?
DB server - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: One difference between the OracleClient and ODP.NET is that ODP.NET's OracleConnection is actually a connection pool. It is possible that your database is timing out the older connections in that pool. You could try using the ValidateConnection property to guarantee that any connection you receive is a good one. Howeever, this costs at least one roundtrip so it might be better to work with your DBA to understand why the timeout is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Networking problems can be some of the trickiest to diagnose without help. First of all, you should contact the DBA for the database in question and ask them to help you.

Have your DBA look into the logs to see if he can find anything.  A firewall could be killing the connection. Or SQL Net could be configured to time out connections.

Does your company have a support contract? If so, I would open a SR and they can help you trace things to narrow down the problem. You will need the cooperation of your DBA to look at the server side.